# SQL Pivot to be used in a View

Tags: sql-server, azure, sum, pivot

I am trying to create a view that will sum the total hours of different work types, as well as the quantity of different products used to a RefNumber.

I have successfully pivoted and summed the hours of work grouped by RefNumber, but now I am scratching my head on how to sum the total product use by Ref Number.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r99hK.jpg)

[Download Excel of data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7riyyld3nrh71io/TEstdataXcl.xlsx?dl=0)

Keep in mind, on some RefNumbers, there will be multiple entries of the same ProductID.  We may have had a few guys using the same product in different quantities.

Here is what I am trying to the Pivot the data too:

[Pivot Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wilMY.jpg)

So far, I have been able to accomplish summing the hours of each work type, and pivoting that data into a single line item grouped by the Ref Number using the following SQL code:

```
SELECT RefNumber,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Blast' THEN THours ELSE NULL END) AS TBlast,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Wheel' THEN THours ELSE NULL End) As TWheel,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Painting' THEN THours ELSE NULL END) AS TPainter,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Mask/Prep' THEN Thours ELSE NULL END) As TMask,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Demask/Touch Up' THEN Thours ELSE NULL END) As TDMask,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Handling: Raw' THEN THours ELSE NULL END) As TRHand,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Handling: Product' THEN Thours ELSE NULL END) As TPHand,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Wheel:Assist' THEN Thours ELSE NULL END) As TAWheel,
SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Metalizing' THEN Thours ELSE NULL END) As TMetal


FROM (
SELECT [RefNumber], [WorkType], SUM (Hours)/60 As THours
  FROM [dbo].[Vw_Beta_CostLog]
  GROUP BY RefNumber, WorkType

) sub
GROUP BY RefNumber
ORDER BY RefNumber
```

Any Ideas on how to modify this code base to Pivot the the distinct product ID's into there own column, and sum the use of those products in a second column?

Also, I want to be able to use this as a view, so I am trying to avoid dynamic pivots.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention, there will be at most 4 unique products used per ref number.

RAW DATA

```
GUID        EmpName         RefNumber       DateInt     Hours   WorkType         ProductID  PQty
P-3468      Gary Hahn       114204      20181008            132 Painting                NULL    NULL
P-3473      Gary Hahn       114204      20181009            204 Painting                NULL    NULL
P-3475      Gary Hahn       114204      20181009            120 Painting                NULL    NULL
F-31915     Jose Flores     114204      20181007            60  Handling: Raw           NULL    NULL
F-31941     Jose Flores     114204      20181008            30  Handling: Raw           NULL    NULL
F-31951     Chris Pollock   114204      20181008            30  Handling: Raw           NULL    NULL
F-32076     Chris Pollock   114204      20181010            120 Handling: Product       NULL    NULL
F-32109     Chris Pollock   114204      20181011            90  Handling: Product       NULL    NULL
F-32301     Daryl Underwood 114204      20181015            15  Handling: Product       NULL    NULL
B-6594      David Martinez  114204      20181007            150 Blast                   NULL    NULL
B-6599      Emiliano Barrios 114204     20181008            66  Blast                   NULL    NULL
B-6617      Jose Molina     114204      20181009            30  Blast                   NULL    NULL
P-3468      Gary Hahn       114204      20181008        NULL    Primer                      11     3
P-3473      Gary Hahn       114204      20181009        NULL    Intermediate            890    2
P-3475      Gary Hahn       114204      20181009        NULL    Finish                  134HG  2
```

Output I am looking for

```
RefNumber   Blast   Painting    Handling: Raw   Handling: Product   Product1    P1Qty   Product2    P2Qty   Product3    P3Qty   
114204      246     456           120            225                    11          3          890  2         134HG            2
```

Comment: Could you provide format data instead of image? thanks

Comment: Is there a preferred way of sharing sample data?  I am just going to upload an Excel file to Drop box unless there is a better way you know of.

Comment: Ideally you should provide your sample data (a simple case is fine) along with your expected output typed in the question instead of these links to pictures and other websites b/c some of us are at locations that deny dropbox links or pictures.  Showing your query attempt is good though.

Comment: If there are 10 parts consumed do you need 20 columns? or, 50 parts consumed you need 100 columns?  *A view must have a fixed set of columns*

Comment: There will be at most 4 products used, so I just need to pivot the product entries to a generic Prod1 Prod2 Prod3, and then sum the quantities of those entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can "pivot" non-numeric data by using `MAX()` instead of `SUM()` and continue to use case expressions as you are already doing.

```
SELECT
    RefNumber
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Blast'             THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) AS TBlast
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Wheel'             THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL End) As TWheel
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Painting'          THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) AS TPainter
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Mask/Prep'         THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TMask
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Demask/Touch Up'   THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TDMask
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Handling: Raw'     THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TRHand
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Handling: Product' THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TPHand
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Wheel:Assist'      THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TAWheel
    , SUM (CASE WHEN WorkType = 'Metalizing'        THEN Hours/60 ELSE NULL END) As TMetal
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN WorkType END)  As WorkType1
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ProductID END) As Product1
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PQty END)      As Qty1

    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN WorkType END)  As WorkType2
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ProductID END) As Product2
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PQty END)      As Qty2

    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN WorkType END)  As WorkType3
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ProductID END) As Product3
    , MAX (CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN PQty END)      As Qty3
FROM (
    SELECT
        [RefNumber]
      , [WorkType]
      , [ProductID]
      , Hours
      , PQty
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RefNumber, case when ProductID IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ORDER BY ProductID) rn
    FROM [Vw_Beta_CostLog]
) sub
GROUP BY
    RefNumber
ORDER BY
    RefNumber
```

Note that you **cannot** create a view which dynamically increases or decreases the number of columns based on how many products are used.

see online demo:  https://rextester.com/SBQUP24417

Comment: I've tried your solution Used_BY and I get invalid column names.   I changed product_id to ProductID and Qty to PQty to match my schema and it still does not work.   I tried Adding ProductID and PQty to the from sub query but then I get aggregation errors.

Comment: the query has been revised, please re-try